# Definition of "novelty song"

Tags: terminology

The problem isn't the definition of "novelty song"
(which I can look up on Wiki anytime) but the
inherent opinionatedness of it (which makes
"Is X an example?" unsuited for SE - for example I'd file
"Dislocated" by Gillian/Glover under this term).

But my question is: *who* has the definition authority?

- Does the band say, "Here, have a novelty song?"
- Does the record company say, "Hey, make some novelty song for teh luz!"
- Does the critics say, "Silly. We file it as novelty song."
- Or will it collectively be decided by the public, say, by playing it as a party evergreen?

Comment: I know two bands personally who each decided to do a novelty song purely to make money in order to continue an otherwise serious career. One did it under a pseudonym, the other bare-facedly under their own regular band name. Both were major world-wide hits, so achieved their goal. Neither was ever followed up by another attempt at a novelty song. (Names redacted to protect the guilty;) [Not posting as an answer because it it a sample set of two & therefore not any kind of 'proof']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "novelty song" is definitely "in the ear of the beholder" — an "I know it when I hear it" kind of music. However, there are a few general properties that many draw from:

- Unusual instrumentation
- Unusual topic for lyrics
- Often funny or unserious
- Overall uniqueness
- Sometimes the only song that artist is known for
- Sometimes achieve a meme-like spot in popular culture

Aside from popular opinion, there are a few "authorities" who might declare a song a "novelty":

1. Dr. Demento: https://www.drdemento.com/
2. Record labels: Novelty Records (1950s-era label) and [Rhino Records](https://www.rhino.com/)
3. Did I mention Dr. Demento?

For example, I would not include "Dislocated" in my list of novelty tunes. It might be a little weird or experimental compared to other music of the time, but not at a level I would call "novelty".

Here are a few that come to mind when I think of novelty tunes:

- "Choo'n Gum" by Teresa Brewer: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pR7kgQBFy9g)
- "They're Coming to Take Me Away" and "I Live in a Split Level Head" by Napolean XIV: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Fn36l_z3WY); [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3Ps5-CicEE)
- "Ready to Rock" by Pianosaurus: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dn4UmJgp24I)
- "Enormous Penis" by Da Vinci's Notebook: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EchbzHN3lek)
- "Dead Puppies" by Ogden Edsel: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EchbzHN3lek)
- "The Chipmunk Song" by Alvin and the Chipmunks: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/joAXosrtocg)
- "King Tut" by Steve Martin: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYbavuReVF4)
- "Fish Heads" by Barnes & Barnes: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cn73Wtem0No) (songs starts at about 2:15)
- "Cement Mixer" by Slim Galliard: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLkFyzzcbSQ)
- "Hawaian War Chant" arr. Spike Jones: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts5cUx6dcko)
- "Rubber Biscuit" by The Blues Brothers: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrjiJp8zr5Y)
- "Grandma Got Run Over by a Reindeer" by Elmo and Patsy: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgIwLeASnkw)

Comment: Frame challenge - Underworld, Born Slippy. Fits all those definitions *except* being considered as a 'novelty song'. It's really, *really* hard to tie this down. I do agree with your definitions broadly, just that there must be some esoteric quality of 'I know this isn't meant to be taken seriously' that is hard to write down in a ruleset.

Comment: Dunno if "[The Most Unwanted Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ8P4DNQA90)" can be considered a "novelty" or just a straight-up "parody"...

Comment: @AndrewT. Now there's a blast from the past. I would definitely call it a novelty. Unless I've confused it with another piece, it was composed based on a survey of what people hated most in music. There was a companion piece based on what people liked most. The irony was that the "bad" piece was by far more enjoyable than the bland and boring "good" piece.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, agreed. "Born Slippy" doesn't have the silliness or irreverence that tends to be associated with "novelty", but it certainly has parts that qualify as "weird", at least.